# get_permalink for custom WordPress page type with correct URL format

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm having trouble with the `get_permalink` WordPress function.

I'm trying to retrieve a custom type page permalink, but the problem is on function result, which doesn't be the correct one (http://myurl.com/mypostalias) but the default format type (http://myurl.com/?slide=32).

I have tried all of:

- `get_permalink(32)`
- `get_permalink(32, true, true)`
- `get_post_permalink (32)`
- `get_post_permalink (32,true,true)`

Same result for all strings... what can I do?

Comment: Have you found the solutions?